# Define data source per DWH or per cube?

Tags: ssas

What is the recommended practice in SSAS: to have a data source per DWH or per Cube?
In all samples I've seen, there is a single DS defined, but only a cube.

Answer (score 2):

You could have multiple cubes in one project.
The datasource is defined for the whole project.
One datasource for each cube is not necessary and sometimes redundant.